# Moodle installation error on Homestead VM

Tags: php, nginx, moodle, homestead

I have installed the Homestead VM and setup the Moodle installation folder on my Mac (OSX Yosemite).  I also created the 'moodledata' folder and gave it the permissions 0777 as well as the folder 'moodledata/sessions' via my system command line (I tried doing this via SSH inside the VM but it didn't appear to change the permissions).  However checking the permissions after doing it via my system showed the folder was writable from inside the VM.

I then moved on to the installation which ran through and created the DB tables and did the check which showed 2 check warnings:
Intl and xmlrpc to check

I don't believe these are essential for initial installation so carried on.  It is when I get to the admin user creation where I am getting a problem.  The page (/user/editadvanced.php?id=2) stops loading any images and when I post the form I get an error: 'Incorrect sesskey submitted, form not accepted!'
I thought this could be down to the session not being writable in the moodledata folder but as I have checked that now I am out of ideas!

I have attached a couple of screenshots.

Many thanks, Mike.

[image: Folder permission from inside the VM]

[image: Moodle page when it starts having problems]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after a good few days of head scratching I fixed my own issue by editing the NGINX config file.  Below is what it was by default:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And this is what I changed it to and it now works:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com; #REPLACE SERVER NAME

    root /var/www/example.com/www/; #REPLACE MOODLE INSTALL PATH
    error_log /var/www/example.com/log/example.com_errors.log; #REPLACE MOODLE ERROR LOG PATH
    access_log /var/www/example.com/log/example.com_access.log; #REPLACE MOODLE ACCESS LOG PATH

    rewrite ^/(.*\.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I haven't had time to see which part/parts of the above config fixed the issue, maybe someone who knows can see straight away?  I suspect it could be the rewrite rule?  Either way I hope this helps someone else in the future and I am really happy to get this working!

Comment: Upon further investigation it was just this line:
rewrite ^/(.*\.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;

Comment: Moodle now has a specific page for nginx configuration: [moodle nginx page](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Nginx)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm is just the rewrite part for that specific config file, although in the [Moodle Nginx](https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Nginx) page it's not documented that way.

My guess is that the `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {` part is doing the same thing as the rewrite rule `rewrite ^/(.*\.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;` and the `location ~ \.php$ {` directive. Will need to make some test changing the location directive to see if that works as well.

Comment: Well I can confirm this doesn't work without the rewrite rule so: why hasn't it been documented by Moodle? Or what are we doing wrong?